# Css shapes support in IE/Firefox

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

Does anyone know if and when IE and firefox will support the css shape features, especially [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside)?

Comment: I am wondering if anybody on SO can even try to answer that question.

Comment: Dunno, hoping for some insiders^^

Comment: You can see at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside that it is "Candidate recommendation" which means that it is in backlog but not actively being implemented - thus noone knows in what version it will be available.

Comment: Good luck :) But I don't think this is on topic here.

Comment: @FlorianGl plz keep the links in English, not everyone reads German.

Comment: No yet, but you can *vote* for it to be implemented on FireFox - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1040714

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## CSS Shapes Module

**What is this?**
[W3 shape module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes/) (2014)
[W3 newest shape module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes-2/) (2015)

From **W3** documentation

> CSS Shapes describe geometric shapes for use in CSS. For Level 1, CSS Shapes can be applied to floats. A circle shape on a float will cause inline content to wrap around the circle shape instead of the float’s bounding box

The current status of the specification is ***Candidate Recommendation***. So its **almost in the current recommendation** so it can more or less be considered in the current web specification.

---

#### IE support?

Lets take a look. There is [hope](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6263716-shapes)!
So Jonathan Sampson shared this idea.

Currently for the newest Edge browser, its current IE status is on the backlog. Tagged with medium priority.

**[Can I use it now?](http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside)**

TL;DR

Run this to see if you can use it:

```css
.left {
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 12ex;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-17deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
p {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<p>
  If this text is inside the shape or all the text is below it, it's not working. If it is aligned to the top edge of the shape, then it is working.
</p>
```